# JSON object to document doc

Tags: java, json, xml, parsing, document

i'm new with Java and was working with a java class which will convert the json file to xml doc and vice verse for Sterling IBM .But the thing is am able to create the class with that functionality but they are expecting the class accept only doc and yfs environment and return only `doc`,so i want to convert `JSONObject` to Document can any one help me to get `doc` from `JsonObject`.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(output);
            Document doc1 = Document.parse( jsonObj.toString() );
```

Here is what i tried with but it giving error as the method parse(string) is undefined for document.
Any other way through which it can be done?

Comment: [mcve] please .. and put some effort into formatting code propery (and not plain text as code ;)

Comment: XML.toJSONObject(output) here output is the string value which is obtained by converting xml to doc and doc to string.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Underscore-java library has static method U.jsonToXml(json).